# My django project is not showing body background

Tags: html, css, django, web-deployment, uwsgi

I have a django project.
I carried it to a new server.
Then i made collectstatics. After that i served my django site on uwsgi.

In my main page html code :

> body id="skin-blur-city"

In **project/static/css/style.css**

```
    #skin-blur-city {
    background-image: url(../img/body/city.jpg);
}
```

statics directory id under my project directory, in django settings file ;

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
```

style.css is in **project/static/css/**

Image file is in **project/static/img/body/city.jpg**

But main page is not showing city.jpg background.
When i look at the source code from browser after i open page,
i see body id="skin-blur-city" is in the html code. But not showing in 
browser.

Browser web console css output is :

Update2 :

I upgraded firefox to Firefox Quantum 60.10esr 64-bit. Now errors are below

```
    Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:6679
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:6792
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:6890
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:6987
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:7512
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:7625
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:7723
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:7820
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:8344
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:8456
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:8555
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:8650
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:9171
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:9283
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:9382
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:9477
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:9913
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:9988
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:10077
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:10166
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:10592
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:10694
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:10806
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:11262
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:11363
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:11474
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:11934
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:12036
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:12148
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:12603
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:12704
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:12815
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:13367
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:13474
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:13861
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:13972
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:14356
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:14463
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:14850
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:14961
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:15344
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:15449
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:15838
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:15947
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:16327
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:16432
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:16806
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:16915
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:17456
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:17558
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:17948
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:18052
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:18447
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:18550
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:18944
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:19049
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:19446
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:19548
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:19943
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:20047
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:20441
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:20544
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:20928
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:21033
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:22254
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:22544
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:22767
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:23064
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:23365
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:24166
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:24322
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:24469
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:24611
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:25400
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:25556
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:25703
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:25845
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:26434
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:26582
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:27182
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:27330
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:28119
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:28264
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:28406
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:28542
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:29072
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:29205
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:29757
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:29877
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:29969
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:30399
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:30515
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:30603
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:31058
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:31173
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:31263
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:31713
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:31827
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:31915
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:32363
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:32480
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:32570
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:33006
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:33114
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:33211
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:33649
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:33755
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:33847
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:34313
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:34420
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:34515
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:34978
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:35084
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:35177
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:35633
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:35740
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:35834
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:36235
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:36336
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:36712
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:36813
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:37188
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:37287
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:37652
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:37757
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:38134
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:38238
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:38612
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:38717
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:39585
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:39681
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:39854
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:39942
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:40043
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:40225
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:40354
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:40787
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:40933
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:41357
Keyframe rule ignored due to bad selector.  animate.min.css:1:41491
Unknown property ‘-moz-osx-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:15:178
Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule ‘@-o-keyframes’.  font-awesome.min.css:15:1165
Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule ‘@-ms-keyframes’.  font-awesome.min.css:15:1248
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:15:1413
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:15:1632
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:15:1856
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:15:2085
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:15:2306
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  form.css:4:2
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  form.css:16:2
Error in parsing value for ‘color’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:80:1
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-expand’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  form.css:94:8
Error in parsing value for ‘background’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:159:16
Error in parsing value for ‘background’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:161:16
Error in parsing value for ‘background’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:162:16
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:169:12
Error in parsing value for ‘opacity’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:170:13
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:638:16
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:665:14
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:738:24
Error in parsing value for ‘background-color’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:752:31
Error in parsing value for ‘background-color’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:787:31
Error in parsing value for ‘background-color’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:814:31
Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1141:25
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1181:14
Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1382:22
Unknown property ‘-moz-box-shadow’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1399:22
Unknown property ‘pointer-event’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1473:19
Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1556:24
Unknown property ‘-moz-opacity’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1601:18
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1604:13
Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1654:24
Unknown property ‘-moz-opacity’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1658:18
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1661:13
Unknown property ‘-moz-border-radius’.  Declaration dropped.  form.css:1711:24
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  calendar.css:213:10
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  calendar.css:353:10
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘selection’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  style.css:44:2
Error in parsing value for ‘overflow-x’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:63:17
Error in parsing value for ‘height’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:276:13
Error in parsing value for ‘cursor’.  Declaration dropped.  style.css:315:13
Expected declaration but found ‘*’.  Skipped to next declaration.  style.css:1799:5
Expected declaration but found ‘*’.  Skipped to next declaration.  style.css:1800:5
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  select2-bootstrap.min.css:1:847
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  select2-bootstrap.min.css:1:1111
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:233
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:785
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-search-cancel-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  select2.min.css:1:1248
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:1617
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-search-cancel-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  select2.min.css:1:2190
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:2498
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:8947
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:9091
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:9985
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:10129
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:11521
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:11661
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:12036
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  select2.min.css:1:12180
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘Alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:624
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:8263
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘Alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:14313
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘Alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:14460
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘Alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:14535
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘Alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:24990
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘Alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  jquery-ui.min.css:4:25153
Error in parsing value for ‘width’.  Declaration dropped.  proj1.generics.css:11:16
Error in parsing value for ‘height’.  Declaration dropped.  proj1.generics.css:12:16
Error in parsing value for ‘line-height’.  Declaration dropped.  proj1.generics.css:13:21
Error in parsing value for ‘-webkit-text-size-adjust’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:140
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-inner-spin-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:7:1418
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-search-cancel-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:7:1652
Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:2441
Unknown property ‘widows’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:2450
Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:3387
Error in parsing value for ‘margin-top’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:22557
Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:22806
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:7:23653
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:7:23700
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:29054
Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:29142
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:29505
Unknown property ‘-moz-osx-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:36771
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:46841
Unknown property ‘zoom’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:75675
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:88388
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:88497
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:89617
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:89671
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:90512
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:90559
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:94454
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:94593
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:94804
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:94974
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:95185
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:95404
Error in parsing value for ‘background-color’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:7:96344
Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule ‘@-ms-viewport’.  bootstrap.min.css:7:98317
Unknown property ‘-moz-text-rendering’.  Declaration dropped.  icons.css:6:25
Unknown property ‘-moz-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.  icons.css:11:25
Unknown property ‘font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.  icons.css:14:20
Expected media feature name but found ‘-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio’.  icons.css:114:18
Expected media feature name but found ‘-o-min-device-pixel-ratio’.  icons.css:116:18
Expected media feature name but found ‘min-device-pixel-ratio’.  icons.css:117:18
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  reps.css:270:15
```

Comment: Your css is probably not loading. Could you check your browser console and see if the css file is failing to load or the image?

Comment: Hi Peter, I added the browser console output to the post. There are lots of errors.

Comment: What browser are you using? You seem to be using a VERY old browser!

Comment: I am using default browser coming with Centos 7.5

Comment: There's no browser called `default`. You should be able to say it's Chrome or Safari or Firefox or Edge or Opera, and the version number.

Comment: Sorry my fault. I was using firefox that came with first installation of centos. I upgraded firefox. Now i am using Firefox 60.1.0esr 64-bit and i added new browsere console logs with update2 in the post. Problem continues with new browser too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176573/discussion-between-peter-and-ivbtar).

Comment: i changed the statics directory permission to 777 but not getting it work. i tried the dull static url from browser to reach a jpg file. But nginx is givving 403 forbidden error on browser.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You showed the way to solution.

Answer (score 0):

This was because of the browser i used.
Style.css had two options for background.
For mobile devices and old browsers it was showing only background color.
For new desktop pc browsers it was showing background picture.
So i used firefox on my pc to open the project instead of firefox browser on centos gnome desktop. Now it is working.